# Video streaming from device via wifi has suddenly gotten much slower, is retries the issue?

Tags: networking, wifi, raspberry-pi

So I use my raspberry pi zero w (raspberry pi with built in wifi) running debian Linux as a security camera, and lately it is streaming much slower now only getting .3 fps whereas I used to get 10. I rebooted but nothing changed and has been like this for a few weeks. The only thing I see is lots of retries in wavemon and /proc/net/wireless. Any ideas?

```
wavemon stats: 
link quality 64% 
signal level -64dBm 
mac retries: multiple per second.

│mode: Managed, access point: BC:64:4B:38:F6:C1
│freq: 2.457 GHz, channel: 10, bitrate: 19.5 Mbit/s
│power mgt: on, tx-power: 31 dBm (1258.93 mW)
│retry: short limit 7, rts/cts: off, frag: off
│encryption: n/a (requires CAP_NET_ADMIN permissions)
```

Comment: Does everybody except for myself know what a "zero w" is? Some incarnation of a Raspberry Pi? There is a /tag for that.